# Delphi default value for procedure parameter

Tags: delphi

```
procedure CaseListMyShares(search: String);
```

I have a procedure like this. Here is content :

```
procedure TFormMain.CaseListMyShares(search: String);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  myShares := obAkasShareApiAdapter.UserShares('1', search, '', '');
  MySharesGrid.RowCount:= Length(myShares) +1;
  MySharesGrid.AddCheckBoxColumn(0, false);
  MySharesGrid.AutoFitColumns;

  for i := 0 to Length(myShares) -1 do
  begin
    MySharesGrid.Cells[1, i+1]:= myShares[i].patientCase;
    MySharesGrid.Cells[2, i+1]:= myShares[i].sharedUser;
    MySharesGrid.Cells[3, i+1]:= myShares[i].creationDate;
    MySharesGrid.Cells[4, i+1]:= statusText[StrToInt(myShares[i].situation) -1];
    MySharesGrid.Cells[5, i+1]:= '';
    MySharesGrid.Cells[6, i+1]:= '';
  end;
end;
```

I want to call this function in two ways which are without any parameter and with a parameter. I found `overload` keyword for procedures but i dont want to write same function two times.

If i call this procedure like `CaseListMyShares('');`, it works.

But can i do below this in delphi ?

```
procedure TFormMain.CaseListMyShares(search = '': String);
```

and call:

```
CaseListMyShares();
```

Comment: Use `procedure TFormMain.CaseListMyShares(const Search: string = '');`.

Comment: @Victoria thank you and why we use const ?

Comment: I would suggest you reading [default parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Default_Parameters) and [constant parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Constant_Parameters) topics.

Comment: @Victoria excellent comments as usual. but why aren't you answering any more?. I find it a waste of your talent/experience to stick just to comments. It is clearly that you still want to help so why not answering. just curious :).

Comment: @Nasreddine, thank you! But my answer would be just those two sentences I've posted in comments. I'm still following FireDAC tag though. Many questions there needs a deeper analysis, not just rewriting what's documented (and that's what I prefer as when we find an issue, it can make FireDAC better than before) :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this. Both methods are useful, and they are often interchangeable. However there are scenarios where one or other is preferable, so it is worth knowing both of the techniques below.

#### Default parameter value

The syntax for this is as follows:

```
procedure DoSomething(Param: string = '');
```

You can call the method like this:

```
DoSomething();
DoSomething('');
```

Both of the above behave in the same way. Indeed when the compiler encounters `DoSomething()` it simply substitutes the default parameter value and compiles the code as though you had written `DoSomething('')`.

Documentation: [Default Parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Default_Parameters).

#### Overloaded methods

```
procedure DoSomething(Param: string); overload;
procedure DoSomething; overload;
```

These methods would be implemented like follows:

```
procedure TMyClass.DoSomething(Param: string);
begin
  // implement logic of the method here
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoSomething;
begin
  DoSomething('');
end;
```

Note that the main body of logic is still implemented once only. When writing overloads in this way there will be one *master* method that performs the work, and a number of other overloads that call that one master method.`

Documentation: [Overloading Procedures and Functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions).